# C++ dll on C# OpenCV

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

I am creating a dll using C++ with OpenCV. This dll is going to be used on C#.

My c++ (dll) code has three functions:

```cpp
extern "C"
{
    bool x(Mat image, Mat gray, Point center)
    {...}
}

extern "C"
{
    bool y(Mat image. Mat gray, Point center)
    {...}
}


extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport)

    int main (const char *cam1 ,int blur)
    {...}
}
```

main function receives a string and an int from the C# code.
In C# I have:

```cs
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
    public static extern int main(string path, int blur);
```

How should I declare the other functions on C# knowing they have arguments with types like Mat and Point?

Comment: You could either translate the mat type to a C# type using structs e.t.c. or you could have another function in your C++ dll, that you could use to initialize a Mat type and then it would return its pointer to the C# code.

Comment: objects on the managed heap can be moved by gc at any time. you need to pin those objects during the dll function call if you let the dll access the row pointer. And that may not be enough if the object contains reference to other objects on the managed heap. It is really up to how complex the Mat type is.

Comment: I forget to tell you that Mat is initialized in the main function. The bool functions are called in the main function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as Owuor suggested and it works.

My C++ bool functions are now

```
extern "C"
{
    bool x(Mat *image, Mat *gray, Point *center)
    {...}
}

extern "C"
{
    bool y(Mat *image, Mat *gray, Point *center)
    {...}
}
```

on C# I have

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
    public static extern int main(string path, int blur);

[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
    public static extern bool (IntPtr ptr1, IntPtr ptr1, IntPtr ptr1);
```